# Short circuit on a coil

Tags: coil, core, short-circuit

We are currently manufacturing some coil assemblies. Our customer reported that some of the coils we shipped had failed once they received them.

Some of the coils failed at the customer's incoming test, whereby the resistance did not meet the specification. The coils which did pass the resistance test later failed once they were cured in the oven for a period of time. All the units which failed at the customers site passed the resistance test before they were shipped out to the customer.

We received some of the failed units back from the customer and we confirmed that the coils had a low resistance, indicating a short-circuit.  This is very strange as they met the resistance specification before they were shipped.

What we concluded was the once the number of turns were achieved on the coil, the ends of copper enamelled wire were soldered to an additional sensor wire and the soldered joint when it touches the core (which is not insulated) and causes a short circuit. Is there anyway I can confirm this with measurements to determine that is the actual root cause and that nothing else is going on?

Comment: The winding should not be connected to the core, right? So one wire touching the core still shouldn't short-circuit the winding. You must have at least 2 short circuits.

Comment: Your English (original revision) reads perfectly Adam but, you do need to include pictures.

Comment: You are correct when you say that the winding should not be connected to the core.  A bit concerned that the we are shipping the coils with no issues yet the customer is claiming that when the measure the resistance value at their incoming inspection, some of the units fail and those that do pass , fail the resistance test after they have cured the assembly in a oven. By way of further information, we have fitted some heat-shrink tubing between the core and the soldered  joint and the problem seems to have gone away for now. But not sure if this is the root cause or not.